# How to assert a function as final for CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp

As we know in CRTP the derived class inherit base, as final inheritance.

What if we want make the derived class not-final but the 'overriding' functions is 'final'?

Is there any way to make it with static_assert?

Code sample:

```cpp
template <typename D>
struct A
{
    int f()
    {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->g();
    }

    int g();
};

struct B : A<B> // usually final, but we want it inheritable
{
    int g() // but this should be 'final'
    {
        // TODO: ???
        return 1;
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    int g() // this is bad
    {
        return 2;
    }

    int h(); // this is permissive
};

#include <iostream>

template <typename D>
void f(A<D>& x)
{
    std::cout << x.f() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    f(b); // OK, it's 1
    f(c); // BAD, it's 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What if we want make the derived class not-final but the 'overriding' functions is 'final'?" - I see *no* use of `final` (or `override`) anywhere in your code. Neither for classes nor functions..

Comment: @JesperJuhl We want something like `final` in dynamic polymorphism, which applies `final` on function but not class, there is no `virtual`, `override` or `final` in CRTP

Answer (score 3):

You can use `final` for two purposes.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

> specifies that a virtual function cannot be overridden in a derived class or that a class cannot be inherited from.

You can use

```
struct B : A<B>
{
    virtual int g() final
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

to allow other classes to derive from `B` but not able to override `g()`.

Another potential side benefit of using `final` is that an optimizing compiler might be able to resolve the function call at compile time instead of resolving at run time (Thanks @JesperJuhl).

Comment: Besides from the not-inheriting / not-overriding semantics, it *might* also make sense to mention that - in *some* situations - using `final` may also help a optimizing compiler better devirtualize function calls.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, interesting. I hadn't thought about it from that point of view. Thanks.

Comment: To use `final` there, the member function needs to be `virtual`.  But then that sort of makes the CRTP somewhat not useful in this case, since it was trying to avoid having a virtual function table and rather rely upon compile time static polymorphism.  Hmmm.  The CRTP will forward to B::g and not to the non-virtual overridden C::g (if that's useful for the OP's use case).

Comment: Your change won't compile for int g() is not **virtual**, **final** is only available for class or virtual function.

Comment: This solution is simple but a vptr introduced, even the dynamic resolution can be optimized, the object size is increased.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution by using private tag in function signature:

```cpp
template <typename D>
struct A
{
    struct internal_tag
    {};

    int f()
    {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->g({});
    }

    int g(internal_tag);
};

struct B : A<B>
{
    int g(internal_tag)
    {
        return 1;
    }

private:
    using A<B>::internal_tag;
};

struct C : B
{
    //  int g(internal_tag) // int g(internal_tag) is prohibited
    //  {
    //      return 2;
    //  }

    int h();
};
```